# SAS Enterprise Guide Automate Copying Folder and Subfolders from Local PC to SAS Server

Tags: automation, sas

I'm trying to automate the process of copying files from my local PC to my SAS server for the purpose of loading all the data in these files to a database. I'm using the Copy Files add-in created by SAS.

The difficulty is that the files i'm copying are created in a changing structure of subfolders and the add-in functions as a separate process that can only traverse the immediate folder which is passed in as a macro variable as shown below.

[Copy Files SAS Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unrjS.png)

I believe I could write a script to get a list of all the subfolders, but how do I pass that into this separate Copy Files process?

Or is it possible on-the-fly in SAS to create multiple "branches" of separate tasks processes and pass in different macro variables?

Thanks

Comment: You should consider posting this at communities.sas.com to get the SAS developers suggestions.

Comment: @Reeza, I noticed Chris H made his very first post on S.O. yesterday.  : ) Maybe he'll jump in.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/4929757/chris-hemedinger

Comment: @Quentin nice! SAS Communities has a response requirement. If no one answers within 48 hours a SAS staff will step in. I find for some of these EG questions they're the best to answer it.

Comment: Good advice @Reeza. I didn't realize SAS Communities had that rule for triggering staff input. Nice.

Comment: Thanks, posted it there. It's close to 48 hours now lol. I will post the solution here if they can answer it. Thanks for the advice.